# Android development studio error with MediaPlayer object

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-6.0-marshmallow

Getting an error in intellij that states I have not defined a onPrepared method in my setOnPreparedListener class.  Have reviewed the documentation and my code for the onPrepared method matches what's defined.
Code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by tim on 4/19/2017.
 *
 */

public class TonePlayerIntentService extends IntentService implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
                                                           MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
                                                            MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "actotracker " + TonePlayerIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    Uri chime = null;
    public TonePlayerIntentService() {
        super(LOG_TAG);
    }

    /**
     * called everytime an intent is launched
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        chime = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"//raw//chime.mp3");

    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent The Intent is provided (inside a PendingIntent) when requestActivityUpdates()
     *               is called.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"IN onHandleIntent");
        this.onStartCommand();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), chime);
        }catch (IOException ie){
            DatabaseProcessor.getInstance().logErrorEvent(ie);
        }
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                cleanUpPlay();
                return true;
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                cleanUpPlay();
            }
        });

        return 1;
    }

    public void cleanUpPlay(){
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

}
```

The error message states that onPrepared(MediaPlayer) must be defined in the setOnPreparedListener class.

Would appreciate information on what I did wrong.  Happily provide more information if requested.

Updated with complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); after you have set your OnPreparedListener

Edit: remove implements and the classnames behind it. Your class is not implementing any interfaces, since you are implementing them inline, and remove this line as well.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

Comment: Did that    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

Comment: Same error reported.  Funny that Lint isn't picking up the error on inspection

Comment: Could you post the complete errorlog. You might be using a wrong import for the MediaPlayer, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: You are also implementing the MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener somewhere else in your class according to your code. The problem might be in that implementation. If You did not you could remove MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener from implements

Comment: There is no errorLog, can't get past the compilation error.

Comment: Code posted is all the code I have for the MediaPlayer implementation.  Not seeing a duplicate onPrepared anywhere in the code.

Comment: You're welcome. Just a small tip for the next time say what kind of error it is in your question such as a conpilation error, lint error, runtime error etc.